# How to install PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL database under Ubuntu?

Tags: postgis, ubuntu

I am quite a newbie in using Postgres under Ubuntu.
I have created a PostgreSQL database and now want to install the PostGIS extension for it so that I can import shapefiles and use the PostGIS commands.
PostGIS is installed. I use the bash shell. Can somebody give me advice?

Comment: Did you run "create extension postgis;" within your db after you installed the packages?

Comment: These instructions have been rock solid for me for a few years - they include all the steps you're asking about: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS22UbuntuPGSQL95Apt

Comment: I updated the instructions for 9.6 and PostGIS 2.3 - I was testing on xenial. https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS23UbuntuPGSQL96Apt

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS is installed as an Extension to each Database.

Once you have created a database,

```
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE Your_Database_Name;"
```

you can install Extensions.

```
psql -d "Your_Database_Name" -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

(or)

```
psql -d "Your_Database_Name" [Enter]

Your_Database_Name=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Then you can use `ogr2ogr` to push Shapefiles to the database, or run the PostGIS functions in your database.

Comment: You can also use shp2pgsql.  You'll need to apt-get install postgis to get that since they have the client command line stuff like shp2pgsql and raster2pgsql in that package instead of as part of the regular postgresql postgis server package